# MySQL - Table trigger prevents insert into table and returns no errors?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, triggers

I am writing my first trigger an a MySQL DB. The idea of the trigger is to prevent anyone from inserting data with a `measurement_date` that falls into the rang of dates that already exists in the table. In other words, I only want data to be inserted that has a LATER date than the very last `measurement_date` for any given source in the table.

After creating a trigger, my C# application that was inserting into the db now hangs, then finally times out, upon executing the insert.  The structure for the table I am inserting into with the trigger is as follows:

```
EXPLAIN mydb.water_data;
 _______________________________________________________________
|Field           |Type          |Null   |Key    |Extra          |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|dataID          |int(11)       |NO     |PRI    |auto_increment |
|cond            |int(11)       |YES    |       |               |
|temp            |int(11)       |YES    |       |               |
|measurment_date |datetime      |YES    |       |               |
|sourceid        |varchar(255)  |YES    |MUL    |               |
```

This is my trigger:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER
    before_insert_waterdata
BEFORE INSERT ON 
    mydb.water_data
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE last_date DATETIME;
DECLARE message VARCHAR(225);    

SELECT WD.measurment_date 
INTO last_date 
FROM mydb.water_data WD
WHERE WD.sourcbefore_insert_waterdataeID = NEW.measurment_date;

IF (NEW.measurment_date <= last_date) 
THEN 
    SET message = "ERROR: Dataset that is being inserted includes a date range that is already present in the database. Insert aborted.";
    SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET message_text = message;
END IF;

END;//
```

The code from my C# application is below:

```
using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                List<string> Rows = new List<string>();

                foreach (var chunk in splitData)
                {
                    StringBuilder sCommand = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO water_data (cond, temp, measurment_date, sourceid) VALUES ");
                    foreach (var date in chunk)
                    {
                        Rows.Add(string.Format("({0}, {1}, '{2}', '{3}')", MySqlHelper.EscapeString(date.cond.ToString()), MySqlHelper.EscapeString("NULL"), MySqlHelper.EscapeString(date.measurment_date.GetValueOrDefault().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH':'mm':'ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)), MySqlHelper.EscapeString(date.sourceid)));
                    }
                    sCommand.Append(string.Join(",", Rows));
                    sCommand.Append(";");

                    using (MySqlCommand myCmd = new MySqlCommand(sCommand.ToString(), connection))
                    {
                        myCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        myCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();  // <------------ The App Crashes right here!!!
                    }
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
            catch(MySqlException ex)
            {
                Debugger.Break();
                ApplicationLog.WriteMessageToLog("ERROR: In Uploader(), There was an error connecting to the database, please check that your connection settings are valid.\n" + ex.Message, true, true, true);
            }
```

Finally, I get a timeout error:

```
Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
```

The objective for this trigger is to prevent anyone from inserting data with a measurement date that already exists in the DB. In other words, I want to prevent duplicate values from being inserted OR values with a date that falls into the date range that already exists for this source.

Why is my insert making the application hang? Is my trigger faulty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the value being sent is invalid then it is failing and then retrying so it is making you wait while it pauses before retrying. Instead of using triggers you could do checks in the code like comparing the value you want to enter to the max date from the table which would produce th same result but without any timeouts and you could also amend the table id need be.

Comment: Yes, I though about this approach. I was under the belief that this would be much faster to do on the MySQL server database rather than in C# code. I was attempting to create some type of trigger that would filter values being inserted to try and remove any duplicate date values and only insert new dates.

Comment: Many people consider using triggers to implement business logic (whichis what you are doing) to be a 'design fail'.  I know you are on MySQL instead of oracle, but the design principles hold true.  Google 'tom kyte trouble with triggers' for a thorough explanation.

Comment: Great article, I was also under the impression that triggers are the coolest thing since sliced bread. The article explains why one shouldn't use them for everything. Thanks for this, I think I will go the code route for my problem. Thank you!